# Python and Selenium xpath for selecting with multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have the following code in selenium but continue to get a syntax error. I'm trying to select an element based on multiple conditions.

```
choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'5') and [contains(@class, 'option')]]")$
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: try `//div[contains(.,'5') and contains(@class, 'option')]`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the *xpath* you have shared as follows :

```
choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'5') and [contains(@class, 'option')]]")$
```

You need to consider a few facts :

- The multiple conditions for selecting the `<div>` tag can't be within nested `[]`. Either you have to specify within one `[]` or within multiple `[]`s.
- The *xpath* shouldn't end with unwanted characters e.g `$`

### Solution

You can rewrite the `xpath` in either of the following ways :

```
choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'5') and contains(@class, 'option')]")
# or
choices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(.,'5')][contains(@class, 'option')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example without using "contains()":

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@name="name" and @value="value"]')
```